# Why my page in bigger than my window in html?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am coding a webpage in HTML and CSS. I haven't set any field about the size of the page. When I run it, I find that my page is bigger than the screen, so I have got a vertical scroll bar. Why is this happening? How can I made it responsive? I want a line that separates the screen into two colors. This line has to start in certain point of the bottom and finish in the top corner, so that the two parts would not be equal.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0giqk.jpg) (Red line should be the end of the screen. Blue area should be removed)

This is my CSS:

```
    body{
       width: 100%;
       height: 114vh;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, yellow 50%, brown 50.1%);
    }
```

If I change the height to 100, two lines (four areas) appear. Anyways, it is not responsive.

Comment: with this code is difficult to say why... remeber that `vw` get the width of the window (if you have a vertical scrollbar it add a horizaontal scrollbar). take a look to `100vdw` ore use `width:100%;`. Remeber that user agent add some margin to the html

Comment: @Sfili_81 I have changed width to 100%, padding to 0 and margin to 0. It solved the width, but the vertical scroll bar is still there.  I want to have the screen divided by a line from bottom to corner. If I set height to 100 it is not responsive and i get two lines.           body{
                width: 100%;
                height: 114vh;
                background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, #db0332 50.1%);
                background-size: 100%;
                background-position: center center;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }